# Motorcycle chariot subject to FL motor vehicle laws

Tags: florida, motor-vehicle

How might the motorcycle chariot's of 1930's Australia fit into today's Florida motor vehicle statutes?  Specifically, could I legally drive one on the streets while operating it from the chariot?

My thinking is it would be classified as a motor vehicle and not a motorcycle, all controls would need to be operable from the chariot, the chariot would need applicable brake/turn signals, and I could probably skirt the safety belt laws since the operator would not be in the front seat.

[image: motorcycle chariot races]

Photo courtesy of [National File and Sound Archive of Australia](https://www.nfsa.gov.au/latest/daredevil-motorcycle-chariot-races) and they are in the video at the 0:54 mark.

Comment: Florida man arrested for racing illegal motorcycle chariot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It wouldn’t

Motor vehicle designs and modifications have to meet certain safety standards - so called “street legal”. These don’t.

Play with them all you like on a private track but they won’t get on the road

Comment: I suspect this is correct, but the answer would be better if it listed at least some of the standards that such a vehicle would not meet, and the codes imposing such standards.