# Would a chariot be road-legal in Minnesota?

Tags: traffic, vehicle, is-x-legal, transportation, minnesota

We already have [a question about motorcycle chariots in Florida](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/43787/12499), but what about *actual*, horse-drawn chariots, and what about Minnesota?

My thinking is that it would probably fall into the same regulatory area as a horse and buggy, but would a chariot actually be road-legal in Minnesota under the aforementioned laws?  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+a+chariot+road+legal&sxsrf=ALiCzsanj3Lsi4CLx7zGF1Uf-Exj5ejrhg:1653264741076&ei=ZdGKYpOnBM23tAarsK2wDQ&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjT7fGMq_T3AhXNG80KHStYC9Y4ChDy0wN6BAgBEDc&biw=1326&bih=668&dpr=1) brings up [a Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/8t88m8/us_is_it_legal_to_drive_a_chariot_on_the_road/) suggesting that they may be road-legal in California, and [another](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cartalk/comments/lpav7w/so_uhh_can_you_legally_register_a_chariot_to/) about vehicle *registration* for a chariot, but nothing else relevant.

Comment: Yes, it would be a horse drawn vehicle, the police will not be out there with measuring sticks saying "this is a chariot, not a buggy".  If the state has Mennonites, they will have laws authorizing horse drawn vehicles.  Mennonites are a religious sect similar to the Amish who reject most technology.q. Very nice neighbors.

Comment: What's the difference between  chariots and a buggy?

Comment: @Nancy A buggy is a small coach without roof and with 4 wheels. But the terminology doesn't seem to be that precise.

Answer (score 2):

The second-broadest category under Minnesota law ([definitions](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/169.011), ch, 169) is "motor vehicle", defined in its entirety:

> (a) "Motor vehicle" means every vehicle which is self-propelled and
> every vehicle which is propelled by electric power obtained from
> overhead trolley wires.
>
> (b) Motor vehicle does not include an electric-assisted bicycle, an
> electric personal assistive mobility device, or a vehicle moved solely
> by human power.

Numerous sub-types of "motor vehicle" or "vehicle" are defined in that section, such as "Class 1 electric-assisted bicycle",
"Farm tractor", "Motorized foot scooter", "Semitrailer" and so on. There is no more-specific category that includes animal-drawn carts of any kind. In [Minnesota v. Hershberger](https://law.justia.com/cases/minnesota/supreme-court/1989/c9-88-2623-2-0.html), 444 N.W.2d 282 we learn that there must be a religious accommodation made with respect to the [slow-moving vehicle](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/169.522) statute, insofar as the law requires slow-moving vehicles to have garish warning signs that conflict with Amish religious beliefs. I set aside the possibility that you are referring to a Hindu ceremony re-enacting the Battle of Kurukshetra (millions of chariots).

The first question is whether a chariot is a "slow-moving vehicle". This is set by the characteristic that it is "designed for operation at a speed of 30 miles per hour or less". This is a question of fact and not law, and opinions on the matter differ, however it is more likely than not that a chariot is not designed to travel faster that 30 mph (the internet generally indicates that the physical speed limitation of a chariot is somewhere around 30 mph). Still, even as a slow-moving vehicle, all that is required is "a triangular slow-moving vehicle emblem". Since there is no statutory distinction between a "cart" and a "chariot", there is no legal basis for treating them differently. The concept of "road-legal" is a consequence of other specific classifications. For example, an ATV is regulated under [§169.045](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/169.045), but that section does not apply to every vehicle. Since there is no special law addressing animal-drawn carts, they are not specifically prohibited therefore they are "road-legal". §169.045 does allow for local restrictions, therefor you would also have to investigate the specific municipality.

Comment: Racing chariots from the horse race track are designed to be operated faster than 30 mph, but those are clearly not roadworthy.